# How to create a custom node template in drupal8 rendering a view within a node page?

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to create custom node template in **Drupal8**. I would like my users accessing "tag" node to be able to view all related content. Therefore I have already created a view presenting all content relating to given tag. Now **I want to render this view in a "tag" node page**.

Following the https://www.drupal.org/node/2165673 I have create a custom theme. I have created `themes/bartikUzbrojeni` directory with the following `bartikUzbrojeni.info.yml`:

```
name: bartikUzbrojeni
type: theme
description: Modifications to the default Bartik theme
core: 8.x
base theme: bartik
```

I have also created `templates` directory within `themes/bartikUzbrojeni` with file `node--tag.html.twig` (being generally copy of node.html.twig from bartik directory).

This seems to more or less work (modifications done within `node--tag.html.twig` are visible within the page) but I have following problems:

1. The page does not look like Bartik one (the bartik theme does not
   seem to be used even though I have marked it as a "base theme"). Please see screen below.
2. I don't know what is the proper way to edit  `node--tag.html.twig` so that it renders a view.

[image]

Comment: is your view a `page view` or a `block view`?

Comment: It is a 'page view'. However, if this matters I can also create a 'block view'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can add the view, use a block view.

Then go to Blocks, and place a block in content.

Select your view block

[image]

In configure click on pages, then type the url of the pages you want it to show. So you put your tags url here. Use the `*` so it shows in all of them.

[image]

**Just noticed I missed a `/` at the start, so it should be `/taxonomy/term/*`**